# Fatal error: Call to undefined method getLoginStatusUrl

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Facebook PHP SDK calls the `Facebook::getLoginStatusUrl()` method, but this method does not exist in the SDK.

I'm using the following code:

```
if ($user) { 
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(); 
} 
else { 
   $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl(); 
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
}
```

What do I do?

Comment: Where exactly are you using it? Can you share some code?

Comment: Actually, I'm using the sample code. Tried the method in question in all SDK and there is no such method.

Do not pass this stretch:

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in the [latest release](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src) of the SDK they have removed the deprecated `getLoginStatusUrl`.

It was in [image]fact not of such use, that's why they have removed I guess.

Anyways, you can just use the `getLoginUrl`

Comment: It's just that I'm using. Verify that in the file example.php it calls the  **getLoginStatusUrl()** method, but it does not exist in the entire SDK.